# Jquery - Change span text color based on numeric value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build a review system in WP with Advanced Custom Fields, but I can't solve this. I want to change the color of a score based on the number. 
For example: if the writer puts 0-40 as score it has to be changed to red; if the writer puts 40-60 it has to be changed to orange; if the writter puts 60-80 it has to be green...

HTML:

```
<div class="r-summary">
   <span id="score">
      <?php the_field('score'); ?> */HERE GOES THE NUMBER WITH THE SCORE
   </span>
 </div>
```

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried, and the PHP is irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5zdemo3j/

(change the score in the HTML section and "Run" to see changes)

```
$(function () {
    // Score Color
    var score = parseInt($('#score').text().trim());
    var color = 'red';
    if (!isNaN(score)) {
        if (score >= 40) {
            color = 'orange';
        }
        if (score >= 60) {
            color = 'green';
        }
        $('#score').css('color', color);
    }
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm!! Thank you :)

Comment: I have a question. What if I wanted to change the background image too? Would that be possible?

Comment: Of course. Study the code and figure out how you could add a background image as well. Hint: Another var like `color`, and another `.css()` call.

Answer (score 4):

Use this function in `document.ready` state if you  are loading the score with PHP so the span will be edited when the document is loaded:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var score = parseInt($("#score").text());
  if (score <= 40) {
    $('#score').css('color', 'red');
  } else if (score > 40 && score <= 60) {
    $('#score').css('color', 'orange');
  } else if (score > 60) {
    $('#score').css('color', 'green');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="r-summary">
  <span id="score">
     50
   </span>
</div>
```

I used `50` as a `score` example here, and you can change it and see the results.

You will proceed like this:

- Get the score from the span.
- According to the score value, change the color of the span.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work as well.

```
<?php
    function the_field() {
        return htmlspecialchars('40-60');
    }
    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .red {
            background: red;
        }
        .orange {
            background: orange;
        }
        .green {
            background: green;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="r-summary">
       <span id="score">
          <?php echo the_field('score'); ?>
       </span>
     </div>    

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){

        var $span = $('.r-summary').find('#score');
        var score = $span.text().trim();
        console.log(score);
        switch(score) {
            case '0-40':
                $span.addClass('red');
                break;
            case '40-60':
                $span.addClass('orange');
                break;
            case '60-80':
                $span.addClass('green');
                break;
        }
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution.

HTML:

```html
<div class="r-summary">
   <span id="score">
       75  <!--Value Printed by PHP-->
   </span>
 </div>
```

jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var score = $('#score').text();
 if (score >= 0 && score <= 40)
 {
     $('#score').css('background-color','red');
 }
    else if (score > 41 && score <= 60)
    {
     $('#score').css('background-color','orange');
 }
    else if (score > 61 && score <= 80)
    {
     $('#score').css('background-color','green');
        $('#score').css('color','white');
 }
});
```

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/byvn9yuL/)!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with native JS.

```
(function () {
    var scoreSpan = document.getElementById("score"),
        score = parseInt(scoreSpan.innerHTML);

    if (score != NaN) {
        if (score >= 0 && score <= 40) {
            scoreSpan.style.color = 'red';
        } else if (score > 40 && score <= 60) {
            scoreSpan.style.color = 'orange';
        } else if (score > 60 && score <= 80) {
            scoreSpan.style.color = 'green';
        } else {
            scoreSpan.style.color = 'black'; // or whatever you want as default
        }
    }
}());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/evrim/tmy74u46/

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                var score = parseInt($("#score").text(),10);
                if(score >= 0 && score < 40){
                    $("#score").removeClass().addClass("redScore");
                }else if(score >= 40 && score < 60){
                    $("#score").removeClass().addClass("orangeScore");
                }else if(score >= 60 && score < 80){
                    $("#score").removeClass().addClass("greenScore");
                }
            }); 
    </script>
    <style>
        .redScore{
            color: #FF0000;
        }   
        .orangeScore{
            color: #FF9933;
        }   
        .greenScore{
            color: #33CC33;
        }   
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="r-summary">
   <span id="score">
     70
   </span>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```